# Can I create a folder and remember the path again after the program is turned off and on? In UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, path, directory

I want to make a folder.

But, whenever i want to access the other folders, like making folder in Picture's Library, I can't access that way.

Because I have to use FutureAccessList.

So, I used that way, but when i close and restart my program,

I had to choice same folder to FutureAccessList.

I think it is annoying to choose a folder every time.

Is there a way to lock the path of the folder even after the program is turned off and on?

Please tell me anything about this.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 3):

future access list returns a **token** (string) and you can store that token in a text file or in your settings or anywhere u want, and next time when u run the app you can get that folder access by supplying that token to future access list and then getting back the folder.

```
var folder = await mru.GetFolderAsync(token);
```

more details on how to track recently used items and future access list , see the docs here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders

Answer (score 0):

Beside what touseefbsb says, there also many ways to do it.

For windows apps:

- Use database store profiles for users
- Local storage for user prfile(Config file/System file)
- Regestry will could store data read/write when you have permissions \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\YourSoftware

For your decision

- Recent folder/files: Windows app with recent behavior requirements(Sounds not)
- Databases: Only if you have a center database server/local database like sqlite
- Local configuration: I think it is easy way for you, if it's a desk top application, you could kindly find app.config usefull
- Regestry: An installtion software of your app, and easy to access registry.

I think your simple choice is application configuration for simple requirements.